# In python/pandas, how to filter the dataframe whice condition stored in list

Tags: python, pandas

in python/pandas, how to filter the dataframe the condition stored in list ？
Below code `ori_data[ori_data['category'] in ['a','d','f']]` can't work

```
import pandas as pd
ori_data = pd.DataFrame({'category':['a','a','b','c','d','f']})
filtered_data = ori_data[ori_data['category'] in ['a','d','f']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, all you need to do is use `.isin()`.

```py
import pandas as pd

ori_data = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']})
filtered_data = ori_data[ori_data['category'].isin(['a', 'd', 'f'])]
```